# Build and run ASP.Net website from Mac OS X terminal

Tags: c#, asp.net, macos, terminal, xamarin-studio

I have an ASP.Net MVC Solution in Xamarin Studio on Mac OS X and when I click on play button, Xamarin Studio automatically build and run my solution and I can check my website from browser.

Is there any way to do this from command line? Is there any terminal command to build and start my website project?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the Xamarin platform however, now that Microsoft made available ASP.NET 5 and CoreCLR to Linux and OS X, you can use [the .NET Version Manager](https://dotnet.github.io/core/getting-started/).

I've used this [John Papa's blogs to get me started](http://www.johnpapa.net/getting-started-with-asp-net-5-on-osx/). Together with [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com), it works very nicely.

They've [a guide on how to setup both together](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/runtimes/ASPnet5) and they've ASP.NET 5 debug on the roadmap.